# How should I implement lazy behaviour with MobX?

Tags: javascript, mobx

The following code is intended to print a reversed list of users as soon as a new user is added, but it doesn't work. The autorun is listening to a lazy calculated var (_userArrayRev), but how to enable the recalculation of that var? The autorun is executed only once, while I expect it to be run three times

And, why does MobX allow me to modify the observable userArray var in AddUser() when enforceactions (useStrict) is set to true?

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });


class Test {
    @observable _userArray = [];
    @observable _userArrayRev = undefined;
    userCount = 0;

    addUser() {
        console.log("Adduser");
        this._userArray.push('user' + this.userCount);
        this.invalidateCache();
    }

//  returns reversed array
    getUsersArrayRev() {
        if (this._userArrayRev == undefined) {
//          console.log("recalculating userArray");
            // TODO: should be reversed
            this._userArrayRev = this._userArray;
        }
        return this._userArrayRev;
    }

    invalidateCache() {
        this._usersArrayRev = undefined;
    }

}

var t = new Test();

autorun(function test () {
    console.log("users: ", t.getUsersArrayRev());
});
t.addUser();
t.addUser();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use `computed` instead of `autorun`. `computed` is more suitable in the case when you want to create readonly lazy variable based on `observable` objects.

**Notice**: I use `slice()` to return a normal array. Observable array is an object rather than an array, be careful of that.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';

class Test {
  @observable _userArray = [];

  @computed get userCount() {
    return this._userArray.length;
  }

  @computed get usersArrayRev() {
    return this._userArray.slice().reverse();
  }

  @action
  addUser() {
    console.log("Adduser");
    const id = this.userCount + 1;
    this._userArray.push(`user${id}`);
    console.log("Reversed users: ", this.usersArrayRev);
  }
}

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  t = new Test();

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.t.usersArrayRev.map(user => <div key={user}>{user}</div>)}
        <button onClick={() => { this.t.addUser(); }}>Add user</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code demo here:

[image: Edit mobx computed]

Comment: I don't see mobx used in the example linked, am I wrong?... and your answer is good but doesn't do exactly what I want, i.e. automatically print the reversed list of users each time adduser is called (without inserting code to print inside addUser, but externally, as in the real world I have a React component that should be re rendered upon an user addition)

Comment: @cdarwin I'm not sure about what do you mean by "print". If you use `t.usersArrayRev.map(user=> <User user={user} />)`, you component will rerender automatically every time you add a new user.

Comment: With print I mean logging to the console the reversed users. However, you should be right, about the React rerendering. Now I go to bed, I'll recheck your answer tomorrow.

Comment: I see that your code works even without @computed (even in strict mode), I still don't understand when computed is needed

Comment: @cdarwin `computed` keyword create a lazy object based on observable value. Without `computed`, it's still a get function, but it might cause out async issues. Think as using the value of state immediately after `setState`, you might get previous value sometimes.